# How to order sections in view

Tags: view

How can I order based on a specific sequence? In my view I have the following items: 
- X1
- X2
- X17

The order in the view is being displayed as:
- X1
- X17
- X2

How can I force the first type of sequence?

[image]

Comment: What is the column type of Section field?

Comment: It is a single line of text

Comment: Then you cannot sort on single line of text like you wanted... However you can add one more number field "order" and sort on that column.

Answer (score 1):

Add leading zeros: X01-05, X01-12, X02-01, X17-01

If you don't want to change the data, add a calculated column that inserts the leading zeros and sort on it, but don't display it.